# Can "as well" follow the verb it modifies?

Tags: grammar

I came across a sentence that begins with

- *I suggest adding a legal reference to include as well a citation to*...

To my ears, "include as well" is incorrect and should be changed to "also include." Or can "as well" or "also" follow the verb it modifies?

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule that you generally should avoid putting an adverb or an adverbial phrase between the verb and its direct object. This is why, for example,

> *to include as well the city of Krasnoy,

sounds incorrect and you should instead write:

> to include the city of Krasnoy as well.

There is an exception to this—if you have a very long direct object, you can put the adverb immediately after the verb. So instead of

> *to include the city of Krasnoy, Lake Malafrena, and the southwestern provinces of Orsinia, as well.

you should write

> to include as well the city of Krasnoy, Lake Malafrena, and the southwestern provinces of Orsinia.

Since you haven't given us the rest of the sentence in your post, it is impossible for us to say whether you should put *as well* after the direct object, or directly after the verb. (For intermediate-length direct objects, both positions are fine.)

If you google "to include as well" in Google books, you find that most of the direct objects are quite long, for example:

> to include as well the very substantial opportunity cost of the time of those students who, if not in school, would be involved in market output,
>
> to include as well a new Original Study by Jonathan Marks on the perils and pitfalls of commercial genetic testing titled "Caveat Emptor: Genealogy for Sale,”
>
> to include as well principles that are equivalent to those of welfare economics,
>
> to include as well an understanding of how science can be used to inform public policy,

Comment: Whose rule is it? I’ve never heard it.

Comment: @Casey: You can find the rule on [this webpage](https://www.scribbr.com/parts-of-speech/adverbs/): *If the verb has a direct object (a thing being acted upon), the adverb should be placed before the verb or at the end of the sentence. It should never be placed between the verb and its object*.

Comment: @Casey: Or this [Cambridge Dictionary webpage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position): *If the verb has an object, the adverb comes after the object.*

Comment: @Casey: I don't know whether sentences that break the rule should be called ungrammatical, or just bad style. Certainly, most writers seem to follow this rule nowadays (allowing for the exception when a direct object is excessively long). I'm not sure they did 200 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The very words "to include as well" are often used ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+include+as+well+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cto%20include%20as%20well%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20those%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cto%20include%20as%20well%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20include%20as%20well%20those%3B%2Cc0), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+include+as+well&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20include%20as%20well%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20include%20as%20well%3B%2Cc0)). There is no problem. This is an expression reckoned with as an idiom ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/well_1#well_idmg_1)) and it has for synonyms "also", "too", "in addition" ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-well)). Since it  has  adverbs for synonyms, it functions as an adverb.

"As well" can follow any verb.

Answer (score 0):

“as well” can certainly follow a verb, e.g.,
“He plays guitar, and he sings as well.” 
But your example sounds awkward to me, too —
although I’m not sure exactly why. 
Then again, “… include also …” sounds wrong, too. 
It might help if you posted more context.

Comment: There are different levels of inclusion in OP's sentence. I'd suggest 'I suggest adding a legal reference, itself including a citation to ....'